# Page Views Counter in PHP is giving the Wrong Results

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I am using the following code to count the unique page views of my posts.

```
$thread_id = 4554;    // thread_id is the unique page id

$sess_key = "page_id_" . $thread_id;

if(!isset($_SESSION[$sess_key]))
{
  $_SESSION[$sess_key] = 0;
}

if($_SESSION[$sess_key]==0)
{
   $query = "UPDATE tbl_threads SET views = (views + 1) WHERE id = {$thread_id}";

   mysqli_query($connection,$query,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

   $_SESSION[$sess_key] = 1;
}
```

But the Problem is, when I add a new post and click it to view it, it adds, some times 3 views to database and some time 2 views to database. When I open the post second time, it adds 1 to database. I am about to pull my hairs, because I did not see any error in this code. It is also not giving me the unique page views. Please analyse my code and tell me where is the problem.

Note: I have pasted this code at the end of the webpage before `</body>` tag.

Comment: See to your access log and add some logging to this script. Like who and when requested this script, what was the request and what were the most important variables values.

Comment: @zerkms Where Can I Check That Log?

Comment: it's your webserver who writes into it (if it's configured to do so)

Comment: You can simplify your code to [this](http://codepad.org/QQbjn3M3).

Comment: Btw, you can store `$sess_key` in the session when you add the post; that should reduce the views by one.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
<?php

$thread_id = 4554;    // thread_id is the unique page id

$sess_key = "page_id_" . $thread_id;
$sessVal = $_SESSION[$sess_key];

if (!isset($sessVal)) {
    $_SESSION[$sess_key] = session_id();
    //Update the count in mysql table
}
```

Comment: So? It would throw a notice. Your code shouldn't normally throw any warnings or notices.